# How to select rows based on a specified set of values in one column which share a value in another column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In reality I have a dataset with 5281 rows and ~ 40 columns. From this I need to select a certain set of values which are duplicates in another row.

To simplify I try to break it down to a df with 2 columns, A and B.

```
d = {'A': [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2], 'B':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

In the image you see the df, and I marked what I want: I want a set of A  = (1, 2) which shares the value in B.

[image]

A little bit of context: I need to drop rows which have duplicates in one column (here as in col B) but only if the duplicates have a certain set of values in another row  (here it is the set 1, 2 of A). And all this I would like to apply directly on the df.

Comment: 1- please provide your input in a reproducible format (no images), 2- also provide the exact expected output and explain how this generalizes

Comment: @mozway I updated the question. I hope it is now a but more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In this solution, `groupby()` will return a series, with the values in A as `sets`, with the values of B as the index. We then check to see if each set is equal to the target set. Lastly we map the boolean series to the original number of rows so we can select just the rows we need.

```
s = {1,2}
df.loc[df['B'].map(df.groupby('B')['A'].agg(set).eq(s))]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  2  a
1  1  a
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much, it worked!
It would be awesome if you could elaborate a little on it.

Comment: i just updated with a short explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
# if the values in A you're interested in
values_of_interest = {1, 2}

# Identify rows with duplicates in 'B' that correspond to the set of interest in 'A'
mask = df.duplicated('B', keep=False) & df['A'].isin(values_of_interest)

# To select these rows
selected_rows = df.loc[mask]

print(selected_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this gives me all rows with are duplicates from B AND the rows which have wether the value 1 or 2 in colum A. At least, that is what I get when I apply it on my dataset. But what I want is only the combination A = 1 and 2 and this set must share the value in B.